# Extract black and white raster drawing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I would like to ask you, what technic(s) do you use when tranfsfering old engineering drawing into new one. For example I wanted to make myself something like this guy did (but even better :-) :-) [image]

So I managed took the original file - but now I am deadly stuck at how to extract the drawing in such a good quality. Tried lot of things, but, as I am no pro -  nothing worked. Can please advise or give me some tips on tutorials? I tried to search it up on google, but didn´t manage to find any...
 [image]

tahnyk you ver much!
best regards
your okuc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Blending Modes.

Invert your image, so the black lines are white.  Set the layer's blending mode to Screen.